# Copy one file at a time from one container to another using azure data factory v2

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy one file from one container to another another in a storage account. the scenario i implemented works fine for a single file. but for multiple files, it is copying both of them in one copy activity. i want the file to be moved one at a time and after a single copy to provide a delay of 1 min, then proceed with the next file copy.

i created a pipeline with the move File template but it did not work for multiple files.
i have taken the source and sink dataset as csv datasets and not binary. i will not be aware of the pattern or the names of the files.

when a user input say about 10 files, i want to copy it one at a time and also provide a delay between each copy. this has to happen between 2 storage account containers.

i have tried to use move files template too. but it did not work for multiple. Please help me.

Comment: Can you share some details of your Copy activity, specifically the Source DataSet? @Andrii's answer should be what you are looking for, but something else may be configured improperly.

Comment: Since you mentioned that you are not aware of the pattern or the names of the files, are you using "Wildcard file path" in the copy activity source?

Answer (score 3):

Sanaa, to force a sequential processing, check the "Sequential" checkbox:
[image]

Time delay could be achieved by adding "Wait" action:
[image]

Comment: Hi.. even after marking as sequential, in the very first copy activity, it would copy both the files and not take the first one.

Comment: How are you monitoring it? What makes you think it is copying both in the FIRST activity?

Comment: While debugging, i can see the files ready as 2 in the first copy activity.

Comment: You need to add @item().name as the source file name. I have it set up so I use a wildcard file path. container/Wildcard folder path/@item().name. Make sure you use @item().name as dynamic content.